# Increase price as increase in kilometer in php

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I am trying to increase the price based on the kilometer provide to it.

> info: 1km = 1000m

**What I'm trying to achieve**

```
if ($km <= 3000) {

 //if provided KM is less than and equal to 3 km
 //output $3.99(base price) 

}elseif ($km > 3000) {
  
//if provided km is greater then 3km and on every +1 km, will increase $0.50c in $3.99
 
//example: if km is 3400 then $3.99(base price) + $0.50c
//example: if km is 4000 then $3.99 + $0.50c
//example: if km is 5000 then $3.99 + $0.50c + $0.50c
//so on..

}
```

But I think my approach is too bad...it would be better if instead of `if conditions` there would be an `algo` who would perform this task using `loop`.

Comment: It seem that you forgot to ask a question

Comment: question is how would I do this using while or for or any kinda loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want ;

```
$base_price=4;
$increase_price=0;
$km=5200;

if($km > 3000){
  $difference_km = ($km-3000)/1000;
  $difference_floor = floor($difference_km);
  $increase_price = $difference_floor*0.5;
}
$output = $base_price + $increase_price;
echo $output;
// output will be 5
```

Comment: Thanks its kinda same but its really help

Answer (score 2):

You only need to compute the kilometers after `3000`. So, for the second case, the price will be:

```php
$output = $base_price + (intval($km - 3000) / 1000) * 0.5;
```

Comment: Oh, I haven't thought about it... thanks very much @omg

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php
    $price = 3.99;
    $kms = [3400, 4000, 5000, 6000];
    foreach ($kms as $km) {
        $profit=0;
        if ($km > 3000) {
            $profit = intval(($km-3000)/1000);
        }
        echo("{$km}km = $$price".str_repeat(' + $0.50c',$profit)."<br>");
    }
    /*Output:
        3400km = $3.99
        4000km = $3.99 + $0.50c
        5000km = $3.99 + $0.50c + $0.50c
        6000km = $3.99 + $0.50c + $0.50c + $0.50c
    */
    die();
?>
```